# Prove that all eigenvalues of a matrix are purely imaginary

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need some help with the following problem. 
Given $A = \left(a_{ij}\right)_{i,j}$ be an $n \times n$ anti-symmetric matrix and $X = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ with $x_i \geq 0$ for all $i$, such that $AX = 0$. Assume that $A$ and $X$ are real. Setting $B$ is the following matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a_{12}x_2 & a_{13}x_3 & \dots & a_{1,n-1}x_{n-1} & a_{1n}x_{n} \\
a_{21}x_1 & 0 & a_{23}x_3 & \dots & a_{2,n-1}x_{n-1} & a_{2n}x_{n} \\
a_{31}x_1 & a_{32}x_2 & 0 & \dots & a_{3,n-1}x_{n-1} & a_{3n}x_{n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{n-1,1}x_1 & a_{n-1,2}x_2 & a_{n-1,3}x_{3} & \dots & 0 & a_{n-1,n}x_{n} \\
a_{n1}x_1 & a_{n2}x_2 & a_{n3}x_{3} & \dots & a_{n,n-1}x_{n-1}  & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Prove that all the eigenvalues of $B$ are purely imaginary.
I can prove that eigenvalues of an anti-symmetric matrix are purely imaginary. I tried to use similar approaches, but it didn't work.
Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: 1) Are the entries of $A$, $B$ and $X$ assumed to be real? 2) 0 is a purely imaginary number, and doesn't have to be singled out as a special case.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for your comments. I modified my post already. $A$ and $X$ are assumed to be real.

Comment: You have $B=AD$ where $D=\operatorname{diag}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. Therefore $B$ and $K=D^{1/2}AD^{1/2}$ share the same characteristic polynomial. Since $K$ is skew-symmetric, its eigenvalues are purely imaginary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your proof. Hence, according to your argument, the hypothesis $AX = 0$ is useless.

Comment: If you multiply B by the vector $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ you will get the zero vector by the assumption that $AX=0$ and therefore 0 is an eigenvalue and 0 is not imaginary.  Since there is a proof that all the eigenvalues (above this comment) are imaginary I assume that means that $x_i$ can't all be positive?

Comment: @Peder We can regard $0$ as a purely imaginary (since it has $0$ real part). The proof requires the non-negativity of all $x_i$.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the answer is negative. Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\
-1 &0 &1\\
-1 & -1 &0\end{pmatrix}\quad X=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ -1\\1
\end{pmatrix} $$
Then
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1& 1\\
-1 & 0 & 1\\
-1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
The eigenvalues of $B$ are equal $0,$ $1$ and $-1.$ The corresponding eigenvectors are $(1,1,1)^t,\ (0,1,1)^t$ and $(1,1,0)^t.$

Comment: @Szwarc Thanks a lot for your counter-example. I missed an assumption to make $X$ unique, which is $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n = 1$. I've just modified it. So, in this case, with your counter-example, the eigenvalues of $B$ seem to be purely imaginary by some quick computations. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My example satisfies $x_1+x_2+x_3=1.$

Comment: Sorry, I missed the condition $x_i \geq 0$ for all $i$. I rephrase this problem from another problem so there are mistakes. Sorry again.

Comment: Ok. Now it seems plausible that your conclusion holds. The sum equal $1$ is not crucial because you can divide $X$ by a positive constant.

Comment: Thanks very much for your remark. I've just modified my question again for the sake of convenience.